Excel VBA - Paste image in clipboard to file
I have a spreadsheet that produces an image in the clipboard.
The sub I have opens a dialog box, and I just need to be able to write the clipboard image to whatever filename the user takes.  Here is the code:
Sub openDialog()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.jpg"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Sub

I have tried to look at existing Stack Overflow articles that appear somewhat similar but they don't work. What can I try next?

Does this help?
